# LINQ Training: Native SQL Queries to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Can anyone point out some good LINQ training resources. Mostly interested in getting some developers that are very skilled with SQL up to speed using Lambda and LINQ queries. They are struggling with some of their more advanced queries and fall back on ExecuteQuery() to kind of do the LINQ thing. Queries that used to be easy in TSQL but are now very difficult for them with LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't recommend LinqPad more highly.  It's a free Windows app that allows you to use Linq interactively against your data source.  It includes tutorials, and allows you to query your data source interactively like you would do in a query analyzer. An excellent resource when trying to make the jump form SQL to Linq.

http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 1):

[Pro LINQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597893) should have most of the information they need in chapters 12-15.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at a utility named Linqer (http://www.sqltolinq.com/). It converts T-SQL to Linq queries. I have found it quite useful at times (I have no relationship with the product).

Also, get LinqPad. This is a must. http://www.linqpad.net/

Randy